# Running a Cron job for every 3 hours using GoDaddy cron job manager

Tags: cron

I am using GoDaddy Linux web hosting. I would like to know how to run a cron job for every 3 hours using the cron job manager in GoDaddy? There are options for hourly, monthly, weekly, daily in the cron job manager.

Answer (score 0):

This should take a simple google but I'll be nice.

```
0 */3 * * * /path-to-script
```

Brush up on this stuff here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

always been useful...

Comment: Well, i know i how to do it in linux. I need how that should be done in GoDaddy cron job manager.

Comment: My bad but it looks like this can help: https://sendy.co/forum/discussion/177/run-cron-job-every-5-minutes-on-godaddy-shared-server/p1